# VBA to remove prefix from excel tab names

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with many tabs. All tabs are named such as: "pboro bz.csv", "pboro fd.csv", "pboro ha.csv", etc.

I am looking to rename all of these "bz.csv", "fd.csv", "ha.csv" instead.

Furthermore, depending on the data another VBA imports, the tab names may have different prefixes. I therefore have a cell (B8) in a sheet titled "Setup" with the prefix I wish to remove, in this case "pboro "

I am trying to use this code:

```
Sub RemovePrefix()
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  Dim Val As String
  Val = Setup.Range("B8").Value
  Const Prefix As String = Val
  For Each WS In Worksheets
    If WS.Name Like Prefix & "*" Then WS.Name = Mid(WS.Name, Len(Prefix) + 1)
  Next
End Sub
```

The code crashes on the line

```
 Const Prefix As String = Val
```

with the error "Constant expression required"

I suspect this is because I am using Dim with Val, then Const with Prexif.
However when I adapt the code to the following:

```
Sub RemovePrefix()
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  Dim Val As String
  Val = Setup.Range("B8").Value
   For Each WS In Worksheets
   If WS.Name Like Val & "*" Then WS.Name = Mid(WS.Name, Len(Val) + 1)
  Next
End Sub
```

I receive the error "Object required" relating to my line of code

```
  Val = Setup.Range("B8").Value
```

I am unsure where I am going wrong (and being a relative VBA noob probably isn't helping).

Comment: Problem 1: a `const` can only be set to something const, which `Val` is not.  So that code will never work.  Your second try is better, but here I suspect with problem 2 that `Setup` is not the code name of one of your sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it's crashing because you never set `Setup` as a worksheet.

```
Dim setup as Worksheet
Set setup = Sheets("Setup")
```

should do the trick.  Also, it looks like `Val` will change, so you wouldn't want to set it as a `Constant`.

Comment: Ah, thought because I had previously set it as worksheet it would carry across- just seen I hadn't set it as a 'public' work sheet.
Many thanks for very fast response!

Comment: just a note that `Setup.Range("B8").Value` would work if you named the worksheet object (inside the VBE) as `Setup`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - You mean if I change the name of the worksheet in the Project view (where it's the sheet icon, then the `ThisWorkbook` icon, and modules under that), you can just do `Setup` without declaring it? Neat! I didn't know that.

Comment: Yes. You can change it, or just refer to it as `Sheet1.Cells(x,y)`. It's a cool feature, but if obviously you can see the issues with reading code that has `Sheet1...` or `Sheet2 ... ` so you have to name them meaningfully.